# Limit Width and Height of Image to be upload

Tags: php

I have read in [phpmanual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) .
The problem that I encountered was to limit the width and height of an image to be uploaded ...
boundary $w=200, and $h=100.
anyone can help me ..?

Comment: You need to specify your exact problem. What have you tried so far? And what isn't working? This is too vague to give a sensible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much we can tell you without more details, but it should be enough to get you started.

This is the basic logic you need to get an image's dimensions, up to you to do something useful in the if block.

```
$maxWidth = 100;
$maxHeight = 100;

list($width, $height) = getimagesize('image.jpg');

if ($width > $maxWidth || $height > $maxHeight) {
    // Cancel upload
}
```